# JSONEncoder with inheritance

Tags: json, swift

I want to use JSONEncoder with class Player which inherit after class Person. I get error "Type 'Player.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'". I found some solutions but in those cases JSON code is similar to make variable type of Person.

Person:

```
class Person: Codable {

    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let gender: Bool
    
    init(name: String, surname: String, gedner: Bool) throws {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.gender = gedner
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        surname = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .surname)
        gender = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .gender)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(self.surname, forKey: .surname)
        try container.encode(self.gender, forKey: .gender)
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name
            case surname
            case gender
    }
}
```

Player:

```
class Player: Person {
    private(set) var number: Int
    
    init(name: String, surname: String, gedner: Bool, number: Int) throws {
        self.number = number
        try super.init(name: name, surname: surname, gedner: gedner)
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.number = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .number)
        try super.init(from: decoder) 
    }
    
    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(surname, forKey: .surname)
        try container.encode(gender, forKey: .gender)
     
    }
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case number
        case name
        case surname
        case gender
    }
}
```

Code:

```
let newPlayer = try Player(name: "Name", surname: "Surname", gedner: true, number: 21)
let data = try encoder.encode(Player) //Error: Type 'Player.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'
```

Comment: You meant to write `try encoder.encode(newPlayer)` here. `Player` is a type, not a value.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I had lot of problems with this code and i didn't expect that might be that simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what Rob says, plus a couple of suggestions:

- When **decoding** you need to provide a type. When **encoding**, you need to provide an object:

```
let newPlayer = try Player(name: "Name", surname: "Surname", gedner: true, number: 21)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
// Provide object
let data = try encoder.encode(newPlayer)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
// Provide type (and data)
let decodedPlayer = try decoder.decode(Player.self, from: data)
```

- if things are as simple as you described in `Person`, the `Person` doesn't need any custom encoding/decoding, you can depend on synthesized one:

```
class Person: Codable {

    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let gender: Bool

    init(name: String, surname: String, gedner: Bool) throws {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.gender = gedner
    }
}
```

The above code will generate the same encoding/decoding as your custom one.

- For sub-classes you always need to specify custom encoding and decoding, BUT only for things that are different from parent. For instance you don't need to duplicate keys, and don't need to encode its classes. Just like you use `super.init`, use `super.encode`. So the code becomes:

```
class Player: Person {
    private(set) var number: Int

    init(name: String, surname: String, gedner: Bool, number: Int) throws {
        self.number = number
        try super.init(name: name, surname: surname, gedner: gedner)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.number = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .number)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case number
    }
}
```

**Unrelated to encoding / decoding**:

- As @LeoDabus mentioned in the comment, it doesn't look like your `init` in `Person` is going to throw any exception, so you may want to remove `throws` from `Person.init`, and `Player.init(name: String...`
- You may also want to correct the parameter name from `gedner` to `gender`:

```
class Person: Codable {

    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let gender: Bool

    init(name: String, surname: String, gender: Bool) {
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.gender = gender
    }
}
```

and

```
class Player: Person {
    private(set) var number: Int

    init(name: String, surname: String, gender: Bool, number: Int) {
        self.number = number
        super.init(name: name, surname: surname, gender: gender)
    }
    // ...
```

Comment: Why `init(name: String, surname: String, gedner: Bool) throws {` if it never throws?

Comment: @LeoDabus no idea: it was in the original code, and I didn't touch anything unrelated to encoding/decoding. I added your suggestion though, together with spelling mistake (that bugged me, lol)